# Сообщения в группе facebook'a видно только их автору

Tags: facebooksdk, facebook, facebook-api

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что сообщения, отправленные через API facebook, видны лишь их автору, кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился сам собой, необходимо было указать "контактный email" и вывести приложение из sandbox'a (в настройках самого приложения)